Windows Speech recognition APIs
I have noticed that in Windows 10 and 11, you can press Win+H to start a "Voice Typing" feature. You speak to a microphone and the widget sends keystrokes to whatever window has the focus. The recognition works surprisingly well, and it does so in multiple languages (e.g. Italian) and locally (no internet connection required, I've tried it by disconnecting the PC).
I was wondering if there is a way to get access to the same speech recognition engine.
Internet search suggests that for Windows developers Microsoft offers many different engines.

In classic .net applications there is the one found under the System.Speech.Recognition namespace. But this doesn't work in Italian1
There is the "Microsoft Speech Platform" (Microsoft.Speech.Recognition) which is similar to System.Speech.Recognition, but intended for server apps. I don't have that installed here2
In UWP applications there is Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition. (this only works online)
There is also the "Speech SDK" (Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech) which looks like a wrapper around a REST API to the Azure Cognitive Services (online).

The question is: what is "voice typing" using, and can I get access to that?


Italian doesn't work, verified via this code:
foreach (RecognizerInfo info in SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(info.Culture);
}

Giving me only en-US, although other language packs are installed and the "voice typing" feature works in Italian on the same machine and user.

I don't have the speech server runtime installed, verified via the absence of a \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech Server\ registry entry. So I don't think the Windows widget is using this.



The app you mention is (on Windows 11) TextInputHost.exe and located in C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy, it surely uses Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech API since it's the newest API and its .dll are present in there (it may also be using other). see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822466/difference-among-microsoft-speech-products-platforms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re

@SimonMourier Can I ask how you know it uses Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech? The app isn't using the internet (since it equally works offline and requires a language pack to be locally installed). While Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Transcription requires access to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp

Oh, there also seems to be something for "embedded speech" in Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/embedded-speech?tabs=windows-target%2Cjre&pivots=programming-language-csharp
This kinda looks like it! Thanks

Thanks to @SimonMourier for his comment.
It looks like the Voice Typing feature is using a hybrid approach where online services are used when available and an offline model is used when the internet isn't accessible.
The API used would be the one from "Azure Cognitive Services":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech
This normally happens online, but they can also provide an "embedded" model which runs locally:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/embedded-speech?tabs=windows-target%2Cjre&pivots=programming-language-csharp
However, to get access to this model, your usecase needs to be approved by Azure (since making it publicly accessible would mean losing some of that sweet sweet money). You can fill out this form to request access:
https://customervoice.microsoft.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR7en2Ais5pxKtso_Pz4b1_xUMFNKUU9RTU1UTkdUMzVYUkxDOFZRMVFGSyQlQCN0PWcu
To then have it rejected withing 10 business days.
When something's too good to be true...

MS seems sympathetic to "educational apps"; if that helps your access request.
